# Problem with the Microsoft .AspNetCore 3.1 package in a .Net Standard 2.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem, I have a visual studio solution with different projects with a microservices architecture, and there is a project with common functionalities for all microservices, in that project I have startup methods in order not to repeat code in the different microservices. the problem is that in the Api project of the microservice I have in the startup the method app.UseEndpoints and when I try to transfer this code to the common project that is in .NET Standard 2.1 it does not let me install the updated version of the nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing Version 2.2.2 date: 12/09/2019 instead the Api project pulls the version of .NET Core 3.1.1

Project API-REST Microservice:

```
assembled Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

When I install that nuget package into the net Standard 2.1 project the assembly is as follows:

```
assembled Microsoft.AspNetCore, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

Could I introduce some functionality from the Microsoft.AspNetCore 3.1.0 package into a net Standard 2.1 project?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. AspNetCore contains more functionality than NetStandard and so you are not linking in the "right" direction.

The proper way is to have a n aspnetcore 3.1 common package that contains (only) those elements that netstandard can not handle.